# No executable found matching command "dotnet-/../.dll" when running dotnet core docker image in Azure Web App on Linux

Tags: c#, azure, docker, travis-ci, .net-core

## 1. Background

I'm currently working on the following build/deployment pipeline:

1. Github (https://github.com/devedse/DeveMazeGeneratorCore)
2. Travis Build (https://travis-ci.org/devedse/DeveMazeGeneratorCore/jobs/196910720)

   - dotnet restore
   - dotnet build
   - dotnet publish
   - docker create image
   - docker publish image to hub
3. Docker image hub (https://hub.docker.com/r/devedse/devemazegeneratorcore/)
4. Use Azure Web App on Linux to execute deployment (http://devemazegeneratorcoredocker.azurewebsites.net/api/mazes/MazePath/512/512)

   - [image: Docker on Azure]
     .

## 2. Problem

Whenever I push something to the Github repository, a build is kicked off and step 1-3 are being executed correctly.
However, the website on Azure is unreachable.

I used SCM to browse to the debug console (https://devemazegeneratorcoredocker.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/Default.cshtml (for future reference)) and executed the following commands to find the log files that were generated by Docker:

[image: Commands KUDU]

and then used the following commands to read them:

```
cat docker_128_err.log
cat docker_128_out.log
```

The out log showed the following results (which seem correct):

```
Login Succeeded
latest: Pulling from devedse/devemazegeneratorcore
5040bd298390: Already exists
fce5728aad85: Already exists
76610ec20bf5: Already exists
51ee4768b31d: Already exists
4dc55ff439a1: Already exists
9cb727c7d7a0: Already exists
2bea08464ad0: Pulling fs layer
2bea08464ad0: Verifying Checksum
2bea08464ad0: Download complete
2bea08464ad0: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:647f3db3daa3330b7eb109a1c604e5bd403c2c7089b3c18c5e9249a9805d3a4d
Status: Downloaded newer image for devedse/devemazegeneratorcore:latest
Login Succeeded
latest: Pulling from devedse/devemazegeneratorcore
Digest: sha256:647f3db3daa3330b7eb109a1c604e5bd403c2c7089b3c18c5e9249a9805d3a4d
Status: Image is up to date for devedse/devemazegeneratorcore:latest
```

The error log however, shows the following errors:

```
2017-01-31T13:11:46.757760723Z No executable found matching command "dotnet-/home/DeveMazeGeneratorCoreWebPublish/DeveMazeGeneratorWeb.dll"
```

The strange thing is, is that whenever I run the image locally, it all works fine:
[image: Dockerlocal]

```
docker run -it --rm -p 0.0.0.0:5001:80 devedse/devemazegeneratorcore:latest
```

Somehow there seems to be a difference in running a Docker image on a Linux machine in Azure, compared to my local Docker installation which runs the Docker images on the default VM that's being installed when you install Docker for Windows.

## 3. Configuration files used:

.travis.yml: (https://github.com/devedse/DeveMazeGeneratorCore/blob/master/.travis.yml)
Dockerfile: (https://github.com/devedse/DeveMazeGeneratorCore/blob/master/Scripts/Docker/Dockerfile)

## 4. Summary

So summarizing, it seems that running Docker on Azure is being executed in a different manner then when doing this locally. Does anyone have an idea on what this could be/how to solve it?

Again, (just for easy reference), the error:

```
2017-01-31T13:11:46.757760723Z No executable found matching command "dotnet-/home/DeveMazeGeneratorCoreWebPublish/DeveMazeGeneratorWeb.dll"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your image to put your application bits somewhere other than /home.

/home is where Azure App Service on Linux bind-mounts the persistent site volume, which is a disk that is shared across instances and is persisted between restarts.

You don't have to use it (you may not have any use for it when running your own image), but anything in your image's /home will disappear at runtime.

Comment: Thanks this finally solved my issue :). Is this documented anywhere?
(PS: http://devemazegeneratorcoredocker.azurewebsites.net/api/mazes/MazePath/512/512 works now ;))

Comment: Not yet, hopefully soon :) Nice demo btw.

Comment: Mazes might be a little bit of an obsession sometimes ^_^. But great that you like it.

Comment: I got a bit of a follow up question regarding this topic. The docker hosted web site still seems to work fine, however, whenever I push a new image to the docker hub, it's not automatically updated in Azure. In fact, I haven't been able to manually trigger a new "installation" of this image either.
Is there any documentation available on how to automate this? (E.g. after the travis build completes and a new image is pushed to the docker hub, that it will automatically trigger the Azure docker container to redownload it and rehost it)?

Comment: Better support for this is in the works. Right now the best option is to modify an application setting on your webapp. This should trigger refresh of the image.