# Dotnet core ENTRYPOINT parameter adds hyphen in Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm trying to configure running simple .NET Core Web API application inside Docker container. My dockerfile contains following `ENTRYPOINT` line:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.name.dll"]
```

Dockerfile builds image proper. When I run it however I have following exception:

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-Project.name.dll"

I don't understand why parameter is transformed in that way (added hyphen). I use `microsoft/dotnet:2.0.0-sdk-stretch` container. Official [documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker) recommends following `ENTRYPOINT` config

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnetapp.dll"]
```

Which is the same as I use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bizarre error message, but it really is saying that the dll can not be found. You can see other examples of this "issue" here: https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/1126#issuecomment-327441394

When you run `dotnet foo.dll`, the `dotnet` application tries to find `foo.dll` and execute it. If the dll is not found, `dotnet` thinks that maybe you are trying to run [a dotnet command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/extensibility#path-based-extensibility) (along the lines of `dotnet foo`, similar to `dotnet build`). This makes `dotnet` look for an executible named `dotnet-foo.dll` and try and execute that. Since that file also doesn't exist, `dotnet` finally errors out that `dotnet-foo.dll` can not be found.

In your case, it looks like `dotnet` couldn't find `Project.name.dll`. Does the dll really exist? Does it exist in the current directory? Perhaps you need to provide the full path to it?

Oh, and if you are running this on Azure, there are some known gotchas, such as [putting your dlls under `/home/` will just not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958888/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-dll-when-running-dotnet-core).

Comment: Very good answer. Thank you. I've executed ENTRYPOINT ["ls"] and now I see I don't have proper files copied. Another question is why Docker see only "obj" directory, but that's not related to hyphen issue :). Thanks omajid.

Comment: Just to mention - Docker didn't see the other stuff due to dockerignore. It's not my config, so I didn't notice :).